# RC2021: expected exponent value, not '6'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, upgrade, porting

When I am upgrading my project to 64-bit in VS2010, it is giving below 2 compiler errors for mentioned code line:

RC1116: RC terminating after preprocessor errors

RC2021: expected exponent value, not '6'.

```
const float AXIS_WIDTH = 2E6F;
```

Could anyone please suggest how can I resolve this issue? This code compiles perfectly in VC++.Net 2003.

Comment: Do you know what it does in VC++.Net?

Comment: You probably want `const float AXIS_WIDTH=2000000.0;`. `2e6f` should work too.

Comment: Works for me with VS2010 (x64) and VS2015 (x64).

Comment: `RC terminating after preprocessor errors` Do you have some macro definition for `E` or `F` or `AXIS_WIDTH`?

Comment: 2E6F is 2000000.0 in VC++.Net and in VS2010 but don't know why it is not working. @SimonKraemer I don't have any macro definition for E, F and AXIS_WIDTH

Comment: Just to verify: Could you please test the following? `const float AXIS_WIDTH = 2EF;` `const float AXIS_WIDTH = 2E;` `const float AXIS_WIDTH = 2F;` `const float AXIS_WIDTH = 2;`

Answer (score 1):

The "RC" prefix in the error number and message is the big clue. It is not the C++ compiler that is tripping over this code, but the [*resource compiler*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381042.aspx).

The resource compiler doesn't even understand the entire C language. It has a minimal preprocessor that does constant substitution. It does not understand variable declarations like:

```
const float AXIS_WIDTH  = 2E6F;    // invalid for resource compiler
const float AXIS_HEIGHT = 2.0;     // invalid for resource compiler
const int   THE_ANSWER  = 42;      // invalid for resource compiler
```

The only thing it understands are macros:

```
#define THE_ANSWER   42
```

Great, so now the only question is, why is this being compiled by the resource compiler. I'm assuming you'd know if you were typing it into your project's resource (.rc) file, so my best guess is that you have it in your `resource.h` file, which gets included in the resource file (which is, in turn, compiled by the resource compiler).

Move this constant declaration into another header file, one that is *not* included in your project's resource file. It will work fine with all versions of the C++ compiler, just as Simon *et al.* have said. Floating-point values do you little good in a resource file anyway.

Comment: Actually abc.h file contains this definition which is included in abc.rc2 file becuase some other variables are # define in abc.h. What if I assign 2000000.0F to AXIS_WIDTH? is this not correct solution?

Comment: You cannot declare variables in header files that are used with the resource compiler. So, no, that will not work. You need to move the variable declaration into a different header file and not include that one in the rc file.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a quick note to say that I encountered this error in a CMake based flow, which was working fine, until today.

I have a template file that includes this:

```
// Executable version information.
VS_VERSION_INFO    VERSIONINFO
FILEVERSION        @PRODUCT_VERSION_MAJOR@,@PRODUCT_VERSION_MINOR@,@PRODUCT_VERSION_PATCH@,@PRODUCT_WC_REVISION@
PRODUCTVERSION     @PRODUCT_VERSION_MAJOR@,@PRODUCT_VERSION_MINOR@,@PRODUCT_VERSION_PATCH@,@PRODUCT_WC_REVISION@
FILEFLAGSMASK      VS_FFI_FILEFLAGSMASK
```

where the @PRODUCT_WC_REVISION@ field is the short hash that I get from Git using:

```bash
git log --pretty=format:'%h' -n 1
```

I was already prefixing this short hash with "0#" because I needed to have a string that started with a number (can't recall exact reason for that now), and that was working fine, previous short hashes had values such as 0165acc1, e103d2e6, a0276738, 51f88779 and 3ff20162.

I tried doing the build today for a new version and the short hash was 895e2140 and this failed with the error:

```bash
error RC2021: expected exponent value, not '2'
```

I looked in the file it mentioned in the error message, but couldn't see anything wrong.  Then I searched for the number 2.  Then I realised what it was, this is the only short hash which starts with a string of numbers followed by the 'e', so the 'e' is being interpreted as an exponent.

I changed my prefix to "0#X" and now my compilation works again.  My assumption is that the X stops the 895e2 as being interpreted as a number.

My advice if you find yourself reading this, look in your file for any occurrence where you have a string of the form (as a regex):

```
[0-9]+[e|E]{1}[0-9]+
```

e.g.
12345E856

and change the string (if you can) to break that pattern.

Comment: Exactly the same situation, cause and solution, thanks!